# "cannot load such file" with rubygems and rvm

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I develop a package called CodeRunner that has a number of add-on package (CodeRunner modules, all with names like ...crmod). One of these is called trinitycrmod.

On Debian stable (wheezy), I have installed RVM using the standard instructions. My .bashrc is setup correctly: the final line is:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

I am using Ruby 2.1.0 (but this error can be reproduced with 1.9.3)

```
rvm use 2.1
```

I have installed CodeRunner and trinitycrmod:

```
gem install coderunner
gem install trinitycrmod
```

Now the CodeRunner gem contains the tool coderunner. One of coderunner's commands is called `ex`, and it evaluates the ruby fragment you give the command. I want to load trinitycrmod.

```
coderunner ex ' require "trinitycrmod"'
```

But **I get an error when loading the file** (which is part of the installed gem).

.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/coderunner-0.13.32/lib/coderunner.rb:118:in `require': cannot load such file -- trinitycrmod (LoadError)

**I don't get this error if I use ruby directly....**

```
ruby `which coderunner` ex ' require "trinitycrmod"'
```

runs fine. I also don't get this error if I use the system ruby:

```
rvm use system
coderunner ex ' require "trinitycrmod"'
```

I also don't get this error if I edit the coderunner bin file and replace ruby_executable_hooks with plain ruby:

```
sed -i s/ruby_executable_hooks/ruby/ `which coderunner`
```

This makes me think that it has to be an error with ruby gems and/or rvm and not my mistake, particularly as this code is all at least 6 months old and has worked fine up till now.

PS My gem environment seems to be just fine....

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.1

  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/edmundhighcock/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:

    - /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0
    - /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:

    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:

    - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:

    - /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin
    - /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin
    - /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin
    - /home/edmundhighcock/.rvm/bin
    - /home/edmundhighcock/Code/scripts
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /bin
    - /usr/local/games
    - /usr/games

Comment: could you issue `irb` then `require "trinitycrmod"`?

Comment: i installed `gsl`, gems `coderunner` and `trinitycrmod`and then tried running the command `coderunner ex ' require "trinitycrmod"'`, and is ran without any error, could you do gem list and check whether `trinitycrmod` is installed or not?

Comment: `irb` then `require "trinitycrmod"` works fine.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that they ran without error for you. I think I will do a clean install of rvm and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

the error message simply states that `trinitycrmod` gem is not installed correctly,
run `gem list` command and check whether the `trinitycrmod` gem is installed or not in your current gemset?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response... it is listed as being properly installed.. `gem list` shows `trinitycrmod (0.2.6)`. The gem is in the right place `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/`